# How to call object inside array

Tags: javascript, react-native

How I call text doraemon to render component

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [
            {text:"doraemon",id:1},
            {text:"naruto", id:2},
        ],
    }
}
```

I already tried `{this.state.array.text}`, but it didn't worked. Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean "call an object"? Do you mean "How do I get the `text` property of these elements?"

Comment: `this.state.array[0].text`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `this.state` has an array in it, you need to reference the individual elements of the array, or in this case:

```
this.state.array[0].text
this.state.array[1].text
```

Presumably you'd have a loop, or expand that with a `map()` call using `id` as the key for rendering.

Keep in mind you'll probably want to give that property a descriptive name other than `array`. Here `widgets` or `items` or `characters` is a better bet than something all too obvious like `array`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.state.array[0].text
this.state.array[1].text
.......................
```

Answer (score 0):

`
This is my ans to your question as in the real world you will be using something like this all the time. And This is my first answer on stack overflow

```
let doraemon = (searchItem) => {
let findDoremon = this.state.array.find(element => element.text === 
searchItem)

return findDoremon.text
}

let fondDoremon = doraemon("doraemon") //<<<<<<<< Here you can enter 
any name that you could like to find

console.log(fondDoremon);
```

Answer (score 0):

An array can hold many values under a single name, and you can access the values by referring to an index number. So if your array contains objects as items. You can assess them by referencing them as the simple array.

In your case it will seem like this :

`this.state.array[index].text`